# Is it true that the generator of maximal ideal in $M_n(P[x])$ can be choosen to be monic?

Tags: ac.commutative-algebra, linear-algebra, matrices, ra.rings-and-algebras, polynomials

Let $P$ be a finite field and $R=M_n(P[x])$ be a matrix polynomial ring.
I want to prove 
that for every  polynomial (not necessary with invertible leading term) $A(x)\in R$ such that $R\cdot A(x)$ is a **maximal left ideal** there exists a  **unique monic** polynomial $B(x)\in R$ such that
$$
R\cdot A(x) = R\cdot B(x)
$$

Crossposted [ME](https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/2375993/is-it-true-that-the-generator-of-maximal-ideal-in-m-npx-can-be-choosen-to).